# Knockout - applyBindings does not respect stopBinding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I took over this legacy .NET webforms application, where KO has been used extensively, and I am trying to get an understanding of KO bindings.

The setup:
- a master page containing:
    - a usercontrol Announcements.ascx
    - a reference to a javascript file named after which page it has been inserted to, lets call it helppageinit.js

The helppageinit.js contains code like this:

```
$(function () {
    var basketViewModel = new AjaxBasket();
    var quickBuy = new QuickBuyViewModel(basketViewModel);

    $.when(basketViewModel.OnLoad, quickBuy.OnLoad).always(function () {
        LeftBasketView(basketViewModel);
        ko.applyBindings({ BasketViewModel: basketViewModel, QuickBuyViewModel: quickBuy });
    });
});
```

I want to add KO code to a new file called AnnouncementsInit.js, which is referenced on the master page. The contents of AnnouncementsInit.js is:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var announcementsViewModel = new AnnouncementsViewModel();

    $.when(announcementsViewModel.OnLoad).always(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(announcementsViewModel, document.getElementById('announcementContainer'));
    });
});

ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function () {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

AnnouncementsViewModel looks like this:

```
AnnouncementsViewModel = function (languange) {
    var _onLoad = $.Deferred();
    var _announcements = ko.observableArray();
    var _singleAnnouncement = ko.observable();
    var _imageWidth = ko.observable("40px");

    var onClose = function () {
        ...code removed...
    };

    _onLoad.resolve();

    return {
        Announcements: _announcements,
        SingleAnnouncement: _singleAnnouncement,
        ImageWidth: _imageWidth,
        OnClose: onClose,
        OnLoad: _onLoad.promise()
    };
};
```

Announements.ascx contains this markup:

```
<div data-bind="stopBinding: true">
    <div id="announcementContainer">
        <div class="popContainer" style="display: none">
            <!-- ko if: SingleAnnouncement -->
            ...markup here
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <div class="divModal" style="display: none" data-cookiename="<%= CookieName %>">
            <!-- ko if: Announcements -->
            ...code here...
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem:
The problem is that stopBinding does not seem to work properly. 'Sometimes', I get this error in the console:

Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: Announcements is not defined;
Bindings value: if: Announcements

I guess the error occurs because applyBindings in helppageInit.js, applies bindings after announcementInit.js has called applyBindings, even though stopBinding should hinder that.

Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: Really interesting question... I've just tried the simple experiment, and now I'm sure that the order of called `applyBindings` is not important (https://jsfiddle.net/ostgals/otf0mf33/). `stopBindings` works as expected, so IMO you have to pay more attention to the error message you get. It says that the error occures in the binding `if: Announcements`, not `if: SingleAnnouncement`.

Comment: Hi f_martinez. By mistake I had removed the part of the code which the errormessage referred to. It has now been added. Thank you for your input, which now make my question more complete.

Comment: Can there be a case in which you `applyBindings` before actually *registering* your custom binding? If knockout encounters an unknown binding name, it will just ignore it. I'm not sure if your code order and asynchronicity allows for it, but it might be worthwhile to make sure it's registered well before any `onLoad` logic returns.

Comment: How do I ensure that my custom binding is registered before any onLoad logic returns? From my experiments I can see that the 'init' function of the stopBinding, is called after some of the applyBindings-calls so you might be on to something. I am quite new to KO and .js in general, so I am unsure how to register my stopBinding before the onLoad logic returns.
It seems the flow is like this:

1) announcementInit.js calls ko.applyBindings(announcementsViewModel, document.getElementById('announcementContainer'));

2) helppageInit.js calls ko.applyBindings, which triggers...stopBinding.Init()